# Commutative property of multiplication does not apply to product to Sum trig identities?

Tags: trigonometry

```
sin u cos v = 1 2 [sin(u + v) + sin(u − v)] 
cos u sin v = 1 2 [sin(u + v) − sin(u − v)]
```

These are from the product-to sum trig tables from My Larson Calculus Book and I am wondering if the commutative property of multiplication is true..... IE . 6*(2x)=(2x)*6 is true.  Then why does this property not apply to the above product to sum trig Identity??

Comment: I suspect this question was meant for [Math.SE]; may I move your question to that site?  Well it seems you are not here at the moment so I will go with my impression and move your question.

Answer (score 1):

Who says it doesn't? But you haven't actually swapped the things being multiplied, you're swapping functions around, so you have to account for that too.

Let's start with the first identity:
$\sin u \cos v = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \sin \left( u + v \right) + \sin \left( u - v\right) \right]$

Then, let's see if we can get to the second one using the first:

$\begin{eqnarray}\cos u \sin v & = & \sin v \cos u \\
& = & \frac{1}{2} \left[ \sin \left( v + u \right) + \sin \left( v - u \right) \right] \\
& = & \frac{1}{2} \left[ \sin \left( u + v \right) + \sin \left( -(u - v) \right) \right] \\
& = & \frac{1}{2} \left[ \sin \left( u + v \right) - \sin \left( u - v \right) \right] \end{eqnarray}$

In the last line, I use the fact that sine is an odd function, and hence $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$.